# Generate minitest skeleton instead of rspec using `bundle gem`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

I am not sure if this is the state-of-the-art way to generate a Ruby project these days:

http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_gem.html

I have this command:

```
bundle gem myapp --test
```

but it generates rspec tests by default.
How can I tell Ruby to generate minitest tests instead of rspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was sufficient:

```
bundle gem myapp --test minitest
```